# Cannot read property 'createStream' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, morgan

> [Type err in the picture][1]   [1]:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pelro.png

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createStream' of undefined
> this is my code: 
const rfsStream = rfs.createStream('server.log',  size: '10M',
interval: '1d', 
path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'logs'), });

app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: rfsStream }));
```

Comment: Did u forget to import the rfs package?

Comment: i use import rfs

Comment: @LaVie did you find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem and solved it as follows:

```
import { createStream } from 'rotating-file-stream';

...

const rfsStream = createStream('server.log', /* etc. */);
```